# Middleware error in geting handshake session Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having problems with Middleware to get the handshake.session in socket.io module to work properly with even a simple example.

1.- I have some error in the cod 
how can be solved

2.- please just need 
get handshake session

Thanks

I am just trying to get this example to work:

```
const KEY = 'express.sid'
  , SECRET = 'express';

var express = require('express'), app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , cookie = express.cookieParser(SECRET)
  , store = new express.session.MemoryStore()
  , session = express.session({secret: SECRET, key: KEY, store: store});


app.configure(function(){
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(cookie);
  app.use(session);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){req.session.ID = "U"+2;});
server.listen(3000);

io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
  cookie(data, {}, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      var sessionID = data.signedCookies[KEY];
      store.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
        if (err || !session) {
          accept(null, false);
        } else {
          data.session = session;
          accept(null, true);
        }
      });
    } else {
      accept(null, false);
    }
  });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var session = socket.handshake.session, id = session.ID;
  console.log(id);
});
```